# Python 2.7.13 - scraping links - following links - grabbing content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a web scraper that will grab all the UK McDonalds addresses, postcodes and phone numbers. I am using an aggregator rather than the McDonalds website.

https://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75639/mcdonalds-restaurant/

I have 'borrowed' some code and repurposed it - but am getting errors. Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

BASE_URL = "https://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75639/mcdonalds-restaurant/"

def get_category_links(section_url):
    html = urlopen(section_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    boccat = soup.find("tr")
    category_links = [BASE_URL + tr.a["href"] for tr in boccat.findAll("h2")]
    return category_links

def get_restaurant_details(category_url):
    html = urlopen(category_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    streetAddress = soup.find("span", "streetAddress").string
    addressLocality = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "addressLocality")]
    addressRegion = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "addressRegion")]
    postalCode = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "postalCode")]
    phoneNumber = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("td", "b")]
    return {"streetAddress": streetAddress,
            "addressLocality": addressLocality,
            "addressRegion": addressRegion,
            "phoneNumber": phoneNumber}
```

The errors look like this:

```
File "<stdin>", line 6
addressRegion = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "addressRegion")]

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    postalCode = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "postalCode")]
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    postalCode= [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("span", "postalCode")]

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    phoneNumber = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("td", "b")]
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    phoneNumber= [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("td", "b")]

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    return {"streetAddress": streetAddress
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return {"streetAddress": streetAddress

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    return {"addressLocality": streetAddress
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return {"streetAddress": streetAddress

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    return {"addressRegion s":treetRegion
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return {"streetRegion": streetRegion

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>    return {"phoneNumber":treetRegion
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return {"streetRegion": streetRegion

IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error when you copy/paste code.  Try to re-write following the correct indentation.